# Taylor/Maclaurin series of $\arctan(e^x - 1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Right, so this keeps bugging me, and I'm probably stuck in some tunnel trying the same thing over and over again.

Give the Maclaurin series of the function $\arctan(e^x - 1)$. up to terms of degree three. Since I try to be as lazy as possible and differentiating this thing sounds like a lot of work, I want to cheat!

Knowing that the Maclaurin series for $\arctan x = x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} + ....$ and the Maclaurin series for $e^x - 1 = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ..... $

So yeah, substition to the resque, $\arctan(e^x - 1)$, use the known series and substite in the known series for $e^x - 1$:

$$[1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3!}x^3] - \frac{[1 + x]}{3}^3 + \frac{[1]}{5!}^5$$

Something along the lines of:

$$[1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{6}x^3] - (\frac{1 + 3x + 3x^2 + x^3}{3})$$

Okay, lets all get 6's:

$$[\frac{6}{6} + \frac{x}{6} + \frac{3}{6}x^2 + \frac{1}{6}x^3] - (\frac{2}{6} + \frac{18x}{6} + \frac{18x^2}{6} + \frac{2x^3}{6})$$

Great... Lets do some algebruh

$$\frac{6}{6} + \frac{x}{6} + \frac{3}{6}x^2 + \frac{1}{6}x^3  - \frac{18x}{6} - \frac{18x^2}{6} - + \frac{1}{6}x^3$$

Join some like terms

$$\frac{6}{6} - \frac{2}{6} + \frac{x}{6} - \frac{18x}{6} + \frac{3}{6}x^2 -  \frac{18x^2}{6} + \frac{1}{6}x^3 - \frac{2}{6}x^3$$

This is so far removed from any of the possible answers and I've spent lots of time on this  one, so it's time to get some real help.

Please help me :)

Comment: You have the series for $e^x$, not $e^x-1$.

Comment: Yeah, the serie's been given as $- 1 + \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$, so that's confusing, but it's clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct expansion should be $e^x-1=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!}$.

Hence substituting it, we get

\begin{align}
\arctan (e^x - 1) &\approx (x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}) - \frac{(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6})^3}{3} \\
&\approx (x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}) - \frac{x^3}{3}\\
&= x+\frac{x^2}2 - \frac{x^3}6
\end{align}

Comment: $e^x = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!}$ and hence $e^x -1= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!}$

Comment: Yeah, I missed the fact your sum starts with $i=1$, not with $i=0$. Thanks.

Comment: don't you have to substitute that part into the $-\frac{x^3}{3}$ term?

Comment: I just have to substitue the linear part, which is $x$, substituting the quadratic part leads to a higher order. hmm.... perhaps I should be clearer, thanks for the feedback

Comment: This is the effect of being focussed on an exercise for too long and not taking a step back. I knew the '1' term needed to go, and yet...